# Magento 2 Replacement for cms/template Object

Tags: magento2, php, cms

In Magento 1, if you wanted to transform an arbitrary block of text, the same as the body of a CMS page or block might be changed, you could use the following model class

```
Mage::getModel('cms/template');
```

This object was also available via the CMS data helper's `getBlockTemplateProcessor` method.

```
Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
```

In Magento 2, there is no CMS data helper object.  There is also no CMS template object.

In Magento 2, if I want to transform an arbitrary string as through it were a CMS page or CMS block, how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you can do this with the

```
Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
```

if you want to "filter" a string with cms "objects" it should be working like this:

```
return $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()
        ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
        ->filter($yourString);
```

hope I understood your question right :X

Comment: Yup, that's the class I was looking for.  Thank you for saving me the code glopping! :)

Comment: Wow, done without a single static method.

Comment: I have used like below in m1. $filter = Mage::getModel('cms/template_filter');
            $filter->setVariables($array);
How to use this in m2?